# Flutter: Triggering events in sub widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

Say a have a Widget A, which has a Widget B as a direct child created in Widget A's build-method. Widget B has the ability to perform an animation, and I want Widget A to be able to trigger this animation. What is the proper way for Widget A to trigger this animation?

This is actually triggering an event in the subtree without re-instantiating Widget B.

My current solution is to save a value passed to Widget B's constructur in WidgetB's state in `initState()`, and in WidgetB's `build()` method checking if the value passed to the constructor matches the state variable. If so, animation is triggered.

Any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Generally speaking, such case should never happen unless there's something wrong in your architecture. What is B's animation ? Maybe it's A that should handle the animation instead

Comment: Also : On stackoverflow, you should avoid opinionated questions. Patterns such as "Is there a better way ?" or such that don't have a clear solution are bad. You should try to reformulate your question into something more "direct".

Comment: @Darky After reading your first reply and giving it some more though, I agree that it is bad practice. My current context was to animate the height of a child of Widget B, but I fixed it by giving Widget B a height factor as parameter, which Widget B multiplied it's sub widget's height with. This way Widget A has control over the height of Widget B's child.